# Exceptions from automongobackup, yet script completes

Tags: mongodb, backup

I am using [automongobackup](https://github.com/micahwedemeyer/automongobackup) to, well, automate the backups of mongodb.

output from the script (to STDERR) has the following exceptions (but the backup completes, and the dump files are created)

```
###### WARNING ######
STDERR written to during mongodump execution. 
The backup probably succeeded, as mongodump sometimes writes to STDERR, but you may wish to scan the error log below:
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: HostAndPort: bad port #
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
exception: connect failed
```

I know that the Host & Port are correct.

If I run `mongodump --host=127.0.0.1:27017 --journal` (which is the effective command from `automongobackup` based on the options set and my reading of the src code) everything runs clean without any error reporting and the dump files are created as expected.

Why would `automongobackup` report connection errors, even tho it does create the dump files, yet a straight call to `mongodump` does not?

- Debian 6.0 Lenny (from Linode image: Latest 3.2 (3.2.1-x86_64-linode23))
- AutoMongoBackup VER 0.9
- mongodb v 2.0.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **have** dived into the code of automongobackup and while shell scripts are not my forte:

## The short answer

Set the following in the config section:

```
# Choose other Server if is Replica-Set Master
REPLICAONSLAVE="no"
```

I had that set to 'yes' (since I hope to move to a replica set before long) - and was being emailed exactly the errors the OP provides, with another email containing the successful log from the script i.e. the same issue.

## The long answer

The wording on that config option implies that the setting will only have an effect **if** this is in a replica set. But later in the code you see that having that config variable set to 'yes' makes it execute

```
mongo --quiet --eval       'rs.conf().members.forEach(function(x){ print(x.host) })'
```

i.e. it asks mongo what the members of the replica set are. However if you're not **in** a replicaset, that returns:

```
TypeError: rs.conf() has no properties
```

From there one thing leads to another inside the script and the errors are presumably the result. From the error messages I'm guessing it tries somewhere to **connect** to a secondary server that

- doesn't exist..
- because it isn't configured..
- because there's no configuration.

I decided against using gWaldo's script because I think automongobackup is more likely to be maintained and improved into the future.

In summary the code that detects if you're in a replica set and how to handle it if you're not needs improving. Setting that option to 'no' will fix it until the script improves - which unfortunately I'm ill qualified to do.

Comment: Congratulatulations on finding the answer, but it doesn't appear that the automongobackup is being maintained; the last update is 3 months ago. With that said, I should put mine up on GitHub

Comment: Should, and have: https://github.com/gwaldo/mongoBackup

Comment: Great: thanks gWaldo! The maintainer of automonogbackup did respond  saying s/he intends to update their script taking account of this 'bug'. But there are reasons to use either.

Answer (score 3):

Without diving into their code, I can't tell you why it's throwing errors.

What I can say is that you've already invested more effort in finding that (apparently broken) tool than if you'd just written a quick shell script to call mongodump (even with rotations) and add it to your crontab.

Here's an example of what you can do if you want to have a daily backups for one week, but keep the Sundays in perpetuity:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Determine day of week. If Sunday, do an archival backup.
## Otherwise, do by day of week.

DOW=`/bin/date +%a`
REPLSET="mlg0"

if [ $DOW == "Sun" ]; then
  DSTRING=`/bin/date +%Y-%m-%d`
  ARCHSTRING="$REPLSET.$DOW.$DSTRING.tgz"
else
  ARCHSTRING="$REPLSET.$DOW"

fi

BACKUP_DIR="/var/shared/backup/mongodb/$ARCHSTRING"

CRON="backup.$ARCHSTRING"
LOCKFILE="/tmp/cron.$CRON.lock"

if [ -f "$LOCKFILE" ]; then
    /usr/bin/logger -t mongodb_backup "$ARCHSTRING locked; skipping"
    exit 0
fi

touch "$LOCKFILE"
/usr/bin/logger -t mongodb_backup "$ARCHSTRING started"
rm -f $BACKUP_DIR
mkdir $BACKUP_DIR
/opt/mongodb-2.0.1/bin/mongodump --host server.domain --out $BACKUP_DIR
rm -f "$LOCKFILE"
/usr/bin/logger -t mongodb_backup "$ARCHSTRING finished"
```

Now a git repo: https://github.com/gwaldo/mongoBackup

Comment: Thanks for the script, I'll take a look at it. Since the automongobackup was referenced on the mongoDB site, I was hoping to use it, as it seemed to be a good standard approach. <shrug>
Not sure about accepting this as an answer, since my question is more about the errors in the `automongobackup` script, but I do appreciate it.

Comment: I hope it helps, but if you think that you're doing everything right and automobgobackup is throwing errors, the only ways to go are to 1) dig into the source code, 2) file a bug report with them, or 3) make or move on to something that works.  It's entirely up to you how you'd like to proceed, but as I see it, these three things are the only real options.

Comment: accepting this answer, as the alternative script is valid.

Comment: Another upvote for this answer. I was having the exact same problem. Decided to use this script instead in the end. Does exactly what I was looking for

Comment: I'm happy that you found it helpful.

Comment: Hi, I tried and adopted your script as it is short and efficient, but I have 2 questions : 1) is dumping in the same folder is no problem or shouldn't the folder need to be removed (rm -rf) ? 2) Reading the code I do not see the weekly archive to be compressed, does it ?

Comment: No, @Nicocube, I had not compressed the weekly archive, as I didn't need it, but you can certainly add compression to the weekly archive.  You may also consider removing old archives.

Comment: With all that said, I'd be happy to receive a pull request to my github repo.

Comment: I'll pull as soon as I'm happy with my reworking of the script. ;) But what about weekdays folders ? As I read the script, we dump over the same folder every week from Monday to Saturday. Is there no issue dumping over ?

Comment: The intention was to only keep the previous week and weekly archives; I actually wanted the weekday backups to overwrite.  If that doesn't meet the needs of the problem that you're trying to solve, then change that on your fork.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to have the benefit of having Replica Sets, but not quite yet as you do not really run in such mode at the moment. Then again, you complain about there errors?

What did you expect to happen? :)

Obviously, if you put "yes" into "REPLICAONSLAVE", then the code would assume that what you want is to find first available slave to take the backup from.

Anyhow, I will add relevant Replica Sets detection code at some point (if the spare time permits) as per issue that somebody opened via github :-)

KW

Comment: nothing about the error output suggests its from the Replication code. So, I'd say what I was expecting was a slightly more informative error message. I thank you for your answer that the configuration needs to be set. I don't recall documentation about the config vars being present at the time I asked this question.

Comment: @chakram88 in the end, you are very right. This project needs to be updated in terms of getting better documentation and finally a decent re-write. I will look into this :) Meanwhile, I welcome any ideas and/or critique -- especially based on the use-cases (real life, or possible ones). Again, thank you for reporting this :)